# Error Unable to deserialize response- TelegramLongPollingBot Java

Tags: java, telegram-bot

When you try to click on the button, it gives this error Unable to deserialize response, please, help me solve it.

> org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException:
> Unable to deserialize response    at
> org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage.deserializeResponse(SendMessage.java:132)
> at
> org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage.deserializeResponse(SendMessage.java:32)
> at
> org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendApiMethod(DefaultAbsSender.java:1009)
> at
> org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.bots.AbsSender.execute(AbsSender.java:64)
> at
> com.example.buns.service.TelegramBotHandler.onUpdateReceived(TelegramBotHandler.java:120)
> at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)     at
> org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
> at
> org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:320)
> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
> Numeric value (5124782738) out of range of int (-2147483648 -
> 2147483647)  at [Source:
> (String)"{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":646,"from":{"id":5124782738,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"WeekTeam
> | Instagram
> Bot","username":"weekteam_instabot"},"chat":{"id":1878528837,"first_name":"Looffy","username":"looffy812","type":"private"},"date":1648562991,"text":"\u0414\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0443\u043f\u043d\u044b\u0435
> \u043a\u043e\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0434\u044b:","reply_markup":{"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"\u041e
> \u0447\u0435\u043c
> \u043a\u0430\u043d\u0430\u043b?","callback_data":"/info"},{"text":""[truncated
> 441 chars]; line: 1, column: 62] (through reference chain:
> org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.ApiResponse["result"]->org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Message["from"]->org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.User["id"])
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:390)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:349)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1822)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:326)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:187)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:324)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:187)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:324)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:187)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4593)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3548)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3531)
> at
> org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage.deserializeResponse(SendMessage.java:124)
> ... 7 more Caused by:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.exc.InputCoercionException: Numeric value
> (5124782738) out of range of int (-2147483648 - 2147483647)  at
> [Source:
> (String)"{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":646,"from":{"id":5124782738,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"WeekTeam
> | Instagram
> Bot","username":"weekteam_instabot"},"chat":{"id":1878528837,"first_name":"Looffy","username":"looffy812","type":"private"},"date":1648562991,"text":"\u0414\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0443\u043f\u043d\u044b\u0435
> \u043a\u043e\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0434\u044b:","reply_markup":{"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"\u041e
> \u0447\u0435\u043c
> \u043a\u0430\u043d\u0430\u043b?","callback_data":"/info"},{"text":""[truncated
> 441 chars]; line: 1, column: 62]  at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportInputCoercion(ParserMinimalBase.java:599)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase.reportOverflowInt(ParserMinimalBase.java:568)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase.convertNumberToInt(ParserBase.java:936)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._parseIntValue(ParserBase.java:849)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase.getIntValue(ParserBase.java:680)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:526)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:506)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:324)
> ... 19 more
> org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException:
> Unable to deserialize response    at
> org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage.deserializeResponse(SendMessage.java:132)
> at
> org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage.deserializeResponse(SendMessage.java:32)
> at
> org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendApiMethod(DefaultAbsSender.java:1009)
> at
> org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.bots.AbsSender.execute(AbsSender.java:64)
> at
> com.example.buns.service.TelegramBotHandler.sendInfoToSupport(TelegramBotHandler.java:216)
> at
> com.example.buns.service.TelegramBotHandler.onUpdateReceived(TelegramBotHandler.java:127)
> at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)     at
> org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
> at
> org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:320)
> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
> Numeric value (5124782738) out of range of int (-2147483648 -
> 2147483647)  at [Source:
> (String)"{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":647,"from":{"id":5124782738,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"WeekTeam
> | Instagram
> Bot","username":"weekteam_instabot"},"chat":{"id":1878528837,"first_name":"Looffy","username":"looffy812","type":"private"},"date":1648562991,"text":"Error
> Unable to deserialize response"}}"; line: 1, column: 62] (through
> reference chain:
> org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.ApiResponse["result"]->org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Message["from"]->org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.User["id"])
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:390)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:349)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1822)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:326)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:187)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:324)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:187)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:324)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:187)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4593)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3548)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3531)
> at
> org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage.deserializeResponse(SendMessage.java:124)
> ... 8 more Caused by:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.exc.InputCoercionException: Numeric value
> (5124782738) out of range of int (-2147483648 - 2147483647)  at
> [Source:
> (String)"{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":647,"from":{"id":5124782738,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"WeekTeam
> | Instagram
> Bot","username":"weekteam_instabot"},"chat":{"id":1878528837,"first_name":"Looffy","username":"looffy812","type":"private"},"date":1648562991,"text":"Error
> Unable to deserialize response"}}"; line: 1, column: 62]  at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportInputCoercion(ParserMinimalBase.java:599)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase.reportOverflowInt(ParserMinimalBase.java:568)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase.convertNumberToInt(ParserBase.java:936)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._parseIntValue(ParserBase.java:849)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase.getIntValue(ParserBase.java:680)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:526)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:506)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:324)
> ... 20 more

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here : The type of id is declared as `int` or `Integer` , you should declare it as `Long`

```
 Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Numeric value 
(5124782738) out of range of int (-2147483648 - 2147483647)  at 
[Source: (String)"{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":646,"from":{"id":5124782738,
```

Comment: Perhaps it?
unbanChatMember.setUserId(Integer.valueOf(chatId));

Comment: change it to :  unbanChatMember.setUserId(Long.valueOf(chatId));

Comment: If I do unbanChatMember.setUserId(Long.valueOf(chatId));
it throws an error and asks to do: wrap the argument with Math.toInt.Exact()

Comment: I changed all Integer to Long, but the error remains the same:

https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/uleyiyudot.csharp

Comment: you should put the code not just the exception stack trace

Comment: Didn't quite understand what you meant

Comment: Maybe I'll throw you my class, and you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: in the class declaration change the type of id to Long , and re-write the setId and getId methods

Comment: In the class declaration, I do not have an id variable, and there are no get and set classes either ..

Comment: I have a class where there is a long id variable, but this and that is already the value of long

Answer (score 1):

I updated the version of the dependency to the latest one and worked for me.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
  <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
  <version>6.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Check the latest version using: [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.telegram/telegrambots)

Comment: Thank you for sharing, time to time, it works for me, but the error still exists, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried chatId in String format. I had a similar error and I solved it by giving String to chatId.

[image]